# Block diagonalization of a symmetric 4$\times$4 matrix.

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, eigenvalues-eigenvectors, diagonalization

I have a symmetric 4$\times$4 matrix, **A**. I need to find it's eigenvalues. The elements are not purely numerical: some elements are exponential functions and so it's extremely difficult to find the eigenvalues using the typical characteristic equation approach.

(Will Jagy): Here is a 4 by 4 matrix. Edit in the actual entries *(Thank you,  Will!*)

The 4 by 4 matrix I'm trying to block diagonalise looks like this:
$$
A =
\begin{bmatrix}e^{2x+y} & 1 & 1 & e^{-2x+y} \\
1 & e^{2x-y} & e^{-2x-y} & 1 \\
1 & e^{-2x-y} & e^{2x-y} & 1 \\
e^{-2x+y} & 1 & 1 & e^{2x+y} \\
\end{bmatrix}
$$
It's quite nasty to deal with: directly calculating the eigenvalues through computer algebra software gives a very nasty answer which doesn't lend well to any analytic uses.

I also have a unitary matrix **S**, which looks like the following:
$$
S =
\begin{bmatrix}0 & 0 & 0 & 1 \\
0 & 0 & 1 & 0 \\
0 & 1 & 0 & 0 \\
1 & 0 & 0 & 0 \\
\end{bmatrix}
$$

Clearly, **SA** = **AS**. I know that somehow, I need to block diagonalise **A** in order to proceed.

How is this kind of block diagonalization typically performed?

Thanks for reading!

*Edit: matrices added!*

Comment: The eigenspaces of $S$ coincide with the eigenspaces of $A$

Comment: Do you mean the values are symbolic when you say that they are exponential functions? If don't think this should be a problem for computer algebra systems like Maple/Sympy(for Pyhton)/Mathematica/symbolic Toolbox for Matlab or Mupad for Matlab. You should first try them and see how complicated the eigenvalues are.

Comment: isentropic you should put in the actual matrix. I edited in a four by four matrix, all you need to do is correct the matrix entires to your symmetric matrix

Comment: @WillJagy Thank you, Will! The matrices I'm now working with are now up there.

Comment: @MrYouMath I've already used Mathematica to calculate the eigenvalues, which provided a horribly complex answer. I know however that a simpler form of the eigenvalues can be found through block diagonalizing the matrix... which I'm not entirely sure how to do!

Answer (score 1):

Take $p = e^{2x}$ and $q = e^y.$  Your matrix now has some fractions, so we multiply through by $pq,$ getting
$$
pqA =
\left(
\begin{array}{cccc}
p^2 q^2 & pq & pq & q^2 \\
pq & p^2 & 1 & pq \\
pq & 1 & p^2 & pq \\
q^2 & pq & pq & p^2 q^2 \\
\end{array}
\right)
$$

The characteristic polynomial of this matrix, variable called $t,$ is
$$  \left( t - (p^2 -1) \right)   \left(t - q^2  (p^2 -1)\right)    \left(  t^2 - (p^2 + 1)(q^2 + 1)  t + q^2  (p^2 - 1)^2    \right) $$
We need the quadratic formula to get two of the eigenvalues.

One quick way is to notice that adding $(1 - p^2)I$ to the matrix makes the two middle rows equal, same as subtracting $(p^2 - 1)I,$ so $p^2 - 1$ is an eigenvalue. Analogous, adding $(q^2 - p^2 q^2)I$ to the matrix makes the first and fourth rows identical, so $p^2 q^2 - q^2= q^2(p^2-1)$ is an eigenvalue.

Answer (score 1):

Thanks to my dissertation supervisor's much welcomed advice, I've found a really nice way to calculate the eigenvalues of the matrix. Block diagonalization is the way after all! The technique itself is super cool, so I wanted to share it.

The first step is to calculate the eigenvectors of **S** and use them to form the following matrix:
$$
\textbf{T} =
\begin{bmatrix}-1 & 0 & 0 & 1 \\
0 & -1 & 1 & 0 \\
0 & 1 & 1 & 0 \\
1 & 0 & 0 & 1 \\
\end{bmatrix}
$$

Calculating the inverse of **T** provides the following:
$$
\textbf{T}^{-1} =
\begin{bmatrix}-\frac{1}{2} & 0 & 0 & \frac{1}{2} \\
0 & -\frac{1}{2} & \frac{1}{2} & 0 \\
0 & \frac{1}{2} & \frac{1}{2} & 0 \\
\frac{1}{2} & 0 & 0 & \frac{1}{2} \\
\end{bmatrix}
$$

By the properties of matrix similarity, it follows that $\textbf{T}^{-1
}\textbf{A}\textbf{T}$ will have the *same eigenvalues as just A*. A fantastic coincidence is that the result of $\textbf{T}^{-1
}\textbf{A}\textbf{T}$ is also a $4\times4$ block-diagonalisable matrix, which means that calculating the eigenvalues is as simple as solving the simpler characteristic equations of the $2\times2$ matrices compromising the blocks.
$$
\textbf{T}^{-1
}\textbf{A}\textbf{T} =
\begin{bmatrix}
e^{2x+y} - e^{-2x+y} & 0 & 0 & 0 \\
0 & e^{2x-y} - e^{-2x-y} & 0 & 0 \\
0 & 0 & e^{2x-y} - e^{-2x-y} & 2 \\
0 & 0 & 2 & e^{2x+y} + e^{-2x+y} \\
\end{bmatrix}
$$

The eigenvalues are now a lot easier to calculate.